# Can I use a CA3081 NPN transistor array instead of a bunch of 2N3904 transistors to drive a bunch of MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet, npn, esp32, transistor-array

I was going to drive a MOSFET from an ESP32 (3.3 V output) with a 2N3904 NPN transistor like this:

[image: Text]

I will need 24 MOSFETs in my project, and that is a lot of soldering.

I found the CA3081 general purpose high current NPN transistor array.

Will it work OK with the ESP32 to drive MOSFETs?

[image: Text]

It would make the circuit much less complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use CA3081.

Vce for saturation of CA3081 is 0.7V when Ice is 1mA.
(In your circuit, Ice is ~1.2mA.)
It is higher than the 2N3904's Vce for saturation ~0.2V in the similar condition.

Thus, if you're driving bipolar power transistor, you cannot use CA3091.
However, the power MOSFET BUZ11 has Vgs threshold voltage 2V for opening.
Thus, CA3081 will just work fine.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, it is very helpful and much appreciated. 
Mike.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but CA30xx are all obsolete; they do still seem to be in ready supply, but consider alternatives:

- ULQ2003 and friends: the Darlington type doesn't help you much, but especially at low load currents, it will saturate (V<sub>CE(sat)</sub>) low enough for general power MOSFETs; avoid using with logic-level MOSFETs.  Alternately, if your MOSFET isn't driving much, perhaps use this for the load directly -- they also have internal clamp diodes for inductive loads (solenoids, relays, small motors, etc.).
- Consider logic-family equivalents, such as SN7406DR.  (Downside: requires 5V logic supply. Might still work at 3.3V? Can also supply via 78L05 or resistor from +12V plus zener shunt regulator.)
- Quads and more of general purpose transistors are surprisingly expensive, and not very helpful on layout area.  Duals however are cheap and plentiful, and help reduce component count a bit, without being obnoxious to layout.  Example: BC847BDW1T3G.
- To save on resistors, consider resistor packs.  Duals and quads are economical and compact, and the quads can usually be used without much cost in layout space.
- To save on both, consider dual pre-biased transistors, e.g. DDC114YU.  You still need pull-ups.
- To drive larger MOSFETs faster (e.g. PWM, SMPS), consider gate drivers like TC4420 and friends.  Duals and probably more are available, with quite strong outputs.  Beware to keep very tight layout around these types: at the currents and speeds they switch at, wires look like inductors.

This assumes a PCB, or production context, and SMT soldering capability.  If you're breadboarding, just get whatever you can find and that fits.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info and tips, the resistor packs are a great idea. That also helps a lot,  
Mike.

Comment: You also got That300, That320, That340 from the THAT coorperation and Alfa produdes a clone of the CA3046, think it's called AS3046. @mike

Comment: @Hearth Metal-gate CMOS do not have LVCMOS compatible input thresholds.

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh, right. I thought I was forgetting something....

Answer (score 6):

I assume your intent is to use pre-drivers/level shifters to increase the BUZ11 Vgs to 12V in order to drive them on as hard as possible. Ok, but perhaps overkill?

Thinking on the physical design. Since these FETs are kind of huge, why not just place the discrete pre-drivers close to them, along with the pull-up resistors? This reduces the gate driver loop area, so less noise pickup and faster switching. Could help.

Speaking of pre-drivers, I prefer using FETs for this, like 2N7002 or BSS138. Then there's no need for the base resistors. Getting rid of the base resistors will probably save more area than using DIP multi-discrete packages, which may have leadtime and sourcing issues.

Answer (score 2):

It'll work but you'll need one IO pin per transistor, which is a problem because you say you need 24 transistors and ESP32 doesn't have 24 available IO pins.

I recommend using a chip from the power logic shift register family, for example [TPIC6C596](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c596.pdf) from TI ; NXP makes an equivalent called "NPIC" instead of "TPIC".

They're basically open drain HC596 shift registers with a much higher allowed output voltage.

You need three IO pins to drive a daisy chain of these chips, unlimited length, and their outputs will work with your MOSFET gate voltage.

They're 5V chips so you'll need a 3V3 to 5V logic level converter, any 74HCT logic chip powered from 5V will do the job, for example a hex buffer.

If you need low current switching, you can also use them directly. They're a bit sensitive to noise though, so if you drive relays I recommend a 10nF cap between the output and ground, in addition to the usual diode. For your MOSFET gate it'll be fine with just the pullup resistor.